# TypeScript service crashed due to 'Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory' error in IntelliJ

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

Here is the configuration of the typescript service in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]

The service crashed and respawned continuously, and here is the log output

```
Process: TypeScript service version: 3.2.1
Process: Default service options: {"baseUrl":"/Users/antkong/dev/myproject/src","experimentalDecorators":true,"importHelpers":false,"jsx":2,"lib":["lib.dom.d.ts","lib.dom.iterable.d.ts","lib.es2018.d.ts"],"moduleResolution":2,"outDir":"/Users/antkong/dev/myproject/target","strict":true,"skipLibCheck":true,"target":2,"sourceMap":true,"module":6,"configFilePath":"/Users/antkong/dev/myproject/tsconfig.json"}
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x1000389cc node::Abort() [/Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node]
 2: 0x100038ba8 node::FatalTryCatch::~FatalTryCatch() [/Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node]
 3: 0x1001a9d5a v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node]
 4: 0x100578772 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node]
 5: 0x100577729 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node]
 6: 0x1005753b8 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node]
 7: 0x1005818fc v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node]
 8: 0x100550294 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node]
 9: 0x1007daf84 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node]
10: 0x4986b2841bd 

Disconnected
```

Is there any way I can increase the heap size of the node process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a hidden option that allows passing arguments to Node.js process that runs TypeScript service - `typescript.service.node.arguments`.

- in **Help | Find action...**, type `registry`
- open *Registry*, locate `typescript.service.node.arguments` key there (you can start typing property name to navigate to it)
- add `--max_old_space_size` option there (`--max_old_space_size=4096`, for example)

See https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-flags/blob/master/flags-0.11.md#max_old_space_size-0-integer

See also https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit - you may find this utility helpful

Comment: What if increasing the heap size does not help. There is some kind of memory leak with IntelliJ and the heap increases slowly until crash. Disposing of Typescript Service every couple of minutes.

Comment: do you have *Show project errors* enabled in TypeScript tool window? If yes, does turning this option off make things any better?
js-language-service is just a wrapper around tsserver provided by Microsoft... Can be related to watching the project dir recursively (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26968, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51139).

Comment: Possibly but I have turned off all those features on IntelliJ. I don't have the creeping crash anymore. But now when I compile I get the error. `Type checking and linting aborted - probably out of memory. Check `memoryLimit` option in ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin configuration.` It always says something about intersection or union types.

Comment: It looks like the fork-ts issue was only during compilation. When just sitting here the IDE will crash on its own, some kind of memory leak.